# Code chunk runs seemingly forever with warning while attempting to assign projection to a raster in R

Tags: r

I am attempting to assign a projection system to a raster using the projectRaster function in R Studio. The chunk does not fail but runs for a very long time (I have left it for over an hour). It shows it is still running but produces the following warning over and over:

Warning: no non-missing arguments to min; returning InfWarning: no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

This is the code I have been using. I am trying to run a land cover classification using random forest but cannot go on because my rasterized training points and the raster I am attempting to classify have different extents (presumably because this raster does not have a projection crs assigned)

```
#Import raster
MosaicedIndicesLVL2022Clip <- stack("C:/Users/j9str/OneDrive/Documents/MAPSS/IFAW/Random Forest R script/Mean_2022_comp_ProjectRaster.tif")
```

```
#Import training points
trpoints <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/Users/j9str/OneDrive/Documents/MAPSS/IFAW/Random Forest R script", layer = "RFTrainingPoints_5classes_xyonly", pointDropZ=TRUE)

plot(trpoints)
```

```
trpoints$classname <- as.factor(trpoints$classname)
is.factor(trpoints$classname)
```

```
trpoints$classvalue <- as.numeric(trpoints$classvalue)
is.numeric(trpoints$classvalue)
```

```
#rasterize training points
raster_trpoints <- rasterize(trpoints,MosaicedIndicesLVL2022Clip, field="classvalue")

colours_trpoints <- c("darkolivegreen","burlywood","palegreen1","cornsilk4","cadetblue")

##Plot the graph with a legend
plot(trpoints,col=colours_trpoints,legend=TRUE)

#label the different landcover types with the right colours

class_son_trpoints <- c("Forest","Cropland","Natural habitat (non-forest)","Degraded","Riverine")
```

```
#Assign projection system based on raster_trpoints
proj <- projectRaster(MosaicedIndicesLVL2022Clip,raster_trpoints)
```

I realise this is just a warning but it seems strange to me that it is taking so long. The raster I am attempting to assign a projection to is not very large at all.